# Distance calculation in a trigger postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I've got two tables "modulo1_cella" and "modulo2_campionamento".

The first, "modulo1_cella" contains polygons, while the latter, "modulo2_campionamento", contains points (samples). Now, I need to assign to each polygon the nearest sample, and the identificative of the sampler itself.

```
                                           Table "public.modulo1_cella"
      Column       |       Type        |                            Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 cella_id          | integer           | not null default nextval('modulo1_cella_cella_id_seq'::regclass)
 nome_cella        | character varying |
 geometria         | geometry          |
 campione_id       | integer           |
 dist_camp         | double precision  |

                                       Table "public.modulo2_campionamento"
          Column          |            Type             |                                    Modifiers
--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 campione_id              | integer                     | not null default nextval('modulo2_campionamento_aria_campione_id_seq'::regclass)
 x_campionamento          | double precision            |
 y_campionamento          | double precision            |
 codice_campione          | character varying(10)       |
 cella_id                 | integer                     |
 geometria                | geometry(Point,4326)        |
```

I'm looking for an INSERT/UPDATE trigger that for each row of "modulo1_cella" table, i.e. for each polygon, returns:

- the nearest sample, "campione_id";
- the corrisponding distance, "dist_camp".

I created a query that works, but I'm not able to convert it to a trigger.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TemporaryTable 
(
    cella_id int,
    campione_id int,
    distanza double precision 
);

INSERT INTO TemporaryTable(cella_id, campione_id, distanza)
SELECT 
DISTINCT ON (m1c.cella_id) m1c.cella_id, m2cmp.campione_id, ST_Distance(m2cmp.geometria::geography, m1c.geometria::geography)  as dist

FROM modulo1_cella As m1c, modulo2_campionamento As m2cmp  
WHERE ST_DWithin(m2cmp.geometria::geography, m1c.geometria::geography, 50000) 
ORDER BY m1c.cella_id, m2cmp.campione_id, ST_Distance(m2cmp.geometria::geography, m1c.geometria::geography);

UPDATE modulo1_cella as mc
SET campione_id=tt.campione_id, dist_camp=tt.distanza
from TemporaryTable as tt
where tt.cella_id=mc.cella_id;

DROP TABLE TemporaryTable;
```

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I can advise - don't do such things on triggers. Triggers seem to be a nice thing on start when you have few of them in your DB. But with time when you have dozens, hundreds or even thousands of them you just lose control of what is going on in your application.
Just create a function for adding/update new record to cella table. And call it when you want to create new cella or update existing one. You will have full control of what is happening without a chain of triggers.

Comment: Also what should happen when you add new polygon or update existing one? Shouln't you recalculate your cella to new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if "geometria" is not `geography` and is instead `geometry`, you should make it a `geography` type on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE modulo2_campionamento
  ALTER COLUMN geometria
  SET DATE TYPE geography(POINT 4326)
  USING (geometria::geography);

ALTER TABLE modulo1_cella
  ALTER COLUMN geometria
  SET DATA TYPE geography(4326)
  USING (geometria::geography);
```

> Now, I need to assign to each polygon the nearest sample, and the identificative of the sampler itself.

You would not normally do this because it's very fast to find the nearest sample using a [KNN search anyway.](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)

```
CREATE INDEX ON modulo1_cella USING gist (geometria);
CREATE INDEX ON modulo2_campionamento USING gist (geometria);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE modulo1_cella;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE modulo2_campionamento;

SELECT *
FROM modulo1_cella As m1c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM modulo2_campionamento As m2cmp
  WHERE ST_DWithin(m2cmp.geometria, m1c.geometria, 50000)
  ORDER BY m2cmp.geometria <-> m1c.geometria, 
    m1c.cella_id,
    m2cmp.campione_id
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS closest_match
```

That's **much** faster than the `DISTINCT ON` query you wrote.

If that is fast enough, I suggest using a `VIEW`. If that's not fast enough, I suggest using a `MATERIALIZE VIEW`. If it's still not fast enough you have a very niche load and it may be worth investigating a solution with triggers. But only then.